# Since when were the US the strongest military power?

Tags: united-states, military

I was wondering since when the USA became the strongest military power. Moreover, which states was in this position before the united states?

Comment: What makes you think the United States is the "strongest military power". The strongest nation is the one that does not have to fight.

Comment: @TylerDurden Maybe he should edit the question to "Since when were the US the strongest military power (after the Vatican City)"?. Anyway, it seems the OP has not even tried to get an answer by himself...

Comment: How do you measure military strength? It isn't merely possession of a larger army or more weapons. There are elements of force projection, diplomacy, strategic bases, etc.  I'll vote to close, but if you want to ignore Whited's law, then the answer is WWII. Alternatively you can research [superpower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpower)

Comment: Switzerland has never been invaded, so that is clearly the best answer.

Comment: Given the way in which Wilson was universally kowtowed to in 1919, at Versailles, the U.S. was clearly the dominant super-power at that moment. Subsequently a decade of neglecting her armed forces from 1920 to 1932 and adopting a completely isolationist policy led Germany, Italy, and Japan into thinking that the role had changed ownership, but that impression was quickly invalidated in the mere 6 months between Dec. 7, 1941, and June 6, 1942. "*It always takes 6 long years to win WW2, but only Japan could lose it in an afternoon.*"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I'd also add "willingness to use military options" as a gauge of strength.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I don't think there's anything to support the claim of the US being the dominant military power back in 1919.

Answer (score 3):

Since World War 2, US became the strongest military power followed by Soviet Union. Before that, England and Germany were competing for the top position.